# GCMBaseIntentService - Wakelock reference is null

Tags: java, android

I'm getting this error on GCM and sometime I receive the message but no notification was generated. Could anyone help me to identify what's the problem?

Here's my code (some business logic code was removed for simplicity):

GcmBroadcastReceiver:

```
public class GcmBroadcastReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // Explicitly specify that GcmIntentService will handle the intent.
    ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(),
            GcmIntentService.class.getName());
    // Start the service, keeping the device awake while it is launching.
    startWakefulService(context, (intent.setComponent(comp)));
    setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK);
  }
}
```

GcmIntentService:

```
public class GcmIntentService extends GCMBaseIntentService {

private static final String TAG = "GCMIntentService";

public GcmIntentService() {
    super(ConstantManager.SENDER_ID);
}

/**
 * Method called on device registered
 **/
@Override
protected void onRegistered(Context context, String registrationId) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Device registered: regId = " + registrationId);
}

/**
 * Method called on device un registred
 * */
@Override
protected void onUnregistered(Context context, String registrationId) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Device unregistered");
}

/**
 * Method called on Receiving a new message
 * */
@Override
protected void onMessage(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Received message");
    String message = intent.getExtras().getString("message");
    String type = intent.getExtras().getString("type");
    int eventId = 0;
    generateNotification(context, message,2,eventId);

}

/**
 * Method called on receiving a deleted message
 * */
@Override
protected void onDeletedMessages(Context context, int total) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Received deleted messages notification");
    // notifies user
    generateNotification(context, "Deleted Message",0,0);
}

/**
 * Method called on Error
 * */
@Override
public void onError(Context context, String errorId) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Received error: " + errorId);
}

@Override
protected boolean onRecoverableError(Context context, String errorId) {
    // log message
    Log.i(TAG, "Received recoverable error: " + errorId);
    return super.onRecoverableError(context, errorId);
}

/**
 * Issues a notification to inform the user that server has sent a message.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
private static void generateNotification(Context context, String message,int type,int referId) {
    int icon = R.drawable.logo_v2;
    long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)
            context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Notification notification = new Notification(icon, message, when);
    Log.i(TAG, "Generating Notification");
    String title = context.getString(R.string.app_name);
    if(GeneralManager.sessionManager.isLoggedIn())
    {
        if(type==2)
        {
            Log.i(TAG, "Type 2");
            Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, PendingEventDetailsActivity.class);
            SharedPreferences pref = context.getSharedPreferences(SessionManager.PREF_NAME, SessionManager.PRIVATE_MODE);
            String userId = pref.getString(SessionManager.KEY_USER_ID,null);
            // set intent so it does not start a new activity
            notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP |
                    Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
            notificationIntent.putExtra("eventId", String.valueOf(referId));
            notificationIntent.putExtra("userId", userId);
            PendingIntent intent =
                    PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
            notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, title, message, intent);
            notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
            // Play default notification sound
            notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;

            //notification.sound = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + context.getPackageName() + "your_sound_file_name.mp3");

            // Vibrate if vibrate is enabled
            notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
            notificationManager.notify(0, notification);      
        }
        else
        {
            Log.i(TAG, "Other type");
            Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, WelcomeActivity.class);
            // set intent so it does not start a new activity
            notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP |
                    Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
            notificationIntent.putExtra("notification", "true");

            PendingIntent intent =
                    PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
            notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, title, message, intent);
            notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

            // Play default notification sound
            notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;

            //notification.sound = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + context.getPackageName() + "your_sound_file_name.mp3");

            // Vibrate if vibrate is enabled
            notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
            notificationManager.notify(0, notification);      
        }
    }

   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this answer is ver late,but hope  it can help someone else.
This problem can be solved by two Methods :

***Method 1 :***
This problem is encountered when WakeLock is released incorrectly i.e. When library tries to release WakeLock that holds nothing (internal lock counter becomes negative).To avoid this you can add following line of code(catching the exception if the WakeLock is not active) on  WakeLocker.release(); :

```css
synchronized (LOCK) {
        // sanity check for null as this is a public method
        if (WakeLock != null) {
            Log.v(TAG, "Releasing wakelocker");
            try {
                 WakeLocker.release();
            } catch (Throwable th) {
                // ignoring this exception, probably wakeLock was already released
            }
        } else {
            // should never happen during normal workflow
            Log.e(TAG, "Reference of WakeLock is null");
        }
    }
```

***Method 2 :***
This is more convenient way of solving the problem, u can use  WakeLocker.isHeld(); on  WakeLocker.release(); i.e.

```css
if (WakeLocker.isHeld())
    WakeLocker.release();
```

Hope it helps anyone.